# Why does /t/ after a consonant (ex: /ˈnaɪn.ti/) produce less air than /t/ at the beginning of word (ex: /ˈtaɪlænd/) or after a vowel (ex: /ˈraɪ.tər/)?

Tags: pronunciation, aspiration

My mother tongue is Vietnamese and I often have difficulty making the English `/t/` sound.

Here is what I discovered.

If a `/t/` is the beginning of word (e.g. `/taɪ/` [tie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tie), `/tɪn/` [tin](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tin), `/ˈtaɪ.lænd/` [Thailand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thailand)) or after a vowel (e.g. `/prəˈtekt/` [protect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protect), `/ˈæd.vɝː.taɪz.mənt/` [advertisement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advertisement)), then when making the `/t/`, we need to release a lot of air from our throat through our mouth. In this case, `/t/` is closer to Vietnamese `/th/`.

However, if `/t/`is after a consonant (ex: /ˈnaɪn.ti/ [ninety](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ninety), /ˈɪn.trəs.tɪd/ [interested](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interested)), then when making the `/t/`, we release just a little bit air from our throat through our mouth. In this case, `/t/` is closer to Vietnamese `/t/`.

To make it easier for you to compare, see the word `/en.təˈteɪn/` [entertain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entertain). The `/t/` in `/tə/` is after `/n/`, so it sounds like Vietnamese `/t/`, and the `/t/` in `/teɪn/` is after `/ə/` so it sounds like Vietnamese `/th/`.

I do not think stressed or unstressed syllable makes a difference. For example, `/t/` in
`/ˈæd.vɝː.taɪz.mənt/` advertisement sounds like Vietnamese `/th/`.

So, *why does `/t/` after a consonant produce less air than `/t/` at the beginning of word or after a vowel?*

Comment: here are some relevant questions; I hope they're helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174536/why-do-the-first-and-last-t-in-taste-sound-different, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210023/why-are-student-and-suspend-not-pronounced-as-written/210027#210027, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125852/pronunciation-of-final-t-sounds-in-english/125909#125909

Comment: @sumelic, the links can answer 30% of my question but not really all factors I mentioned in my question

Comment: OK, can you maybe edit your question to clarify which 70% of it is still unanswered? Just to give some background, the sound like Vietnamese "th" is called an "aspirated stop" or "aspirated plosive" and is transcribed as /tʰ/ in the International Phonetic Alphabet, while the sound like Vietnamese /t/ is called an "unaspirated stop/plosive" and is transcribed with a single /t/ in the IPA. Is your question about how to tell if a word spelled with "t" has an aspirated or an unaspirated stop? If so, the following might be of use: http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/vot-is-more.html

Comment: so what does "at the beginning of a syllable" mean?  so */t/* is at the beginning of a syllable */taɪz/*  in */ˈæd.vɝː.taɪz.mənt/*, right? Not necessary at the beginning of the word as */taɪ/* in */ˈtaɪ.lænd/* ?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the difference between unaspirated /t/ & aspirated /t/. Can you write your answer? Thank you

Comment: Note: the US pronunciation that Cambridge gives for _advertisement_ seems to me to be slightly inaccurate. At least, I’ve never heard it pronounced ['ædvɝːtaɪzmənt] with a long [ɝː]; it’s always either [ædˈvɝːɾɪzmənt] (with either [æ] or [ə] at the beginning) or [ˈædvɚtaɪzmənt].

Comment: [Strongly related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/620545/2085).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distinction between these two sounds, both generally represented by the letter "t" in English, is actually also made for "p" and "k." Each of these sounds is transcribed /t/ /p/ /k/ in "broad" phonetic transcriptions, but in a "narrow," more detailed transcription, there are two main types that are recognized by phoneticians.

We call one type "aspirated," and in transcriptions that distinguish the two, it's represented by the letter with a superscript "h" after it: [tʰ] [pʰ] [kʰ]. (The sound /tʰ/ exists in Vietnamese, where it is written "th"; the other two sounds do not.)

The second type is called "unaspirated": it's represented by plain [t] [p] [k]. These should correspond approximately to the Vietnamese sounds written with the letters "t," "p," and "k."

When to use one or the other is explained as follows on [John Wells's phonetics blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/vot-is-more.html):

> English [p t k] are **aspirated**
>
> - when they occur at the beginning of a syllable in which the vowel is
>     strong.
>
> They are **unaspirated**
>
> - when preceded by s at the beginning of a syllable
> - when followed by any FRICATIVE, as in *lapse* læps, *depth* depθ
> - if immediately followed by
>     another plosive as with the k in doctor ˈdɒktə || ˈdɑːktər. The
>     release stage of the first plosive is then usually inaudible
>     (‘masked’).

I'd add to this that it's safe to aspirate any "t," "p," or "k" at the very start of a word, no matter what sound comes after it.

The above rules apply to pretty much all varieties of English. As you can see, using these rules requires a fair amount of knowledge of the sound patterns of English: you'll need to know how a particular word is divided in syllables.

When /t/ comes after a vowel or after "r" and before a "weak" vowel like [ə] (*writer*) or [ɪ] (*writing*), or before a completely unstressed [oʊ] (*grotto*) or [i] (*jetty*), there may be differences in American and British pronunciation.

Many American varieties of English have a third pronunciation of "t" which is written in the International Phonetic Alphabet as [ɾ]. A "d" in this position is usually pronounced the same way, so this is less commonly transcribed as [d] by some people.

The pronunciation of "t" as [ɾ] usually does not occur before a strong vowel sound (any other vowel than [ə] or [ɪ]), as described in the following question: [Why do photons and protons exhibit such anomalous behavior?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100210/why-do-photons-and-protons-exhibit-such-anomalous-behavior)

Comment: Surely that /ɾ/ should be written [ɾ].

Comment: @Sumelic, what about the slightly aspirated T. Ex, in */en.təˈteɪn/* entertain, t in */tə/* is after */n/* & it sounds like slightly aspirated T

Comment: @Sumelic, I think slightly aspirated T close to Vietnamese "/t/*, while unaspirated T almost has no sound

Comment: A reduced pronunciation of /t/ (corresponding to your ‘third’ pronunciation) exists in all varieties of English as well, as far as I know—its exact manifestation just varies. AmE, SAE, and AusE/NZE will usually have [ɾ], IrE frequently [ɾ], [ʔ], [h], or [[ɹ̝̊\]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_fricative#Voiceless_alveolar_non-sibilant_fricative), different dialects of BrE either [ɾ], [t], or [ʔ], etc. (And you could add in a bit about the special circumstances around /nt/, as well as how strong vs. weak vowels are distributed.)

Comment: Nice answer - but why's there no aspiration in *ninety*?

Comment: @Araucaria: I still need to add that part. Since "ninety" ends in an unstressed vowel, the t may be flapped.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/620545/2085).

Answer (score 0):

### **Short answer**

In General American English, a /t/ will tend to be voiced when it occurs after a nasal and before a weak vowel. This sounds a bit like a /d/ to many listeners. If you're looking at an IPA transcription in a good dictionary, such as Cambridge Dictionaries Online you should see that the /t/ has a little diacritic underneath. The symbol will look like this: `t̬`. Voiced /t/s have no aspiration as is explained further below.

### **Detailed answer**

It is a well known fact that /t/ is liable to be a voiced tap when it occurs after a vowel and before another weak vowel. So for example the /t/ in *water* will be pronounced [ɾ] in Gen Am. The Cambridge Dictionaries Online transcription for this is /ˈwɑː.t̬ɚ/. That little downwards arrow there, which should be directly underneath the 't', shows that this /t/ is likely to be voiced.

However, what's less well-known is that /t/ is also likely to be realised as voiced when it occurs between certain voiced consonants and a weak vowel. So for example /t/ may also be voiced when it occurs after /r, l, m, n, ŋ/ and before a weak vowel. So we will probably hear a tap or other voiced allophone in the following words:

- [porter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/porter)
- [halterneck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/halterneck)
- [ninety](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ninety)
- [sphincter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sphincter)

If you look at the transcriptions for those words in the links you will see the voiced-*t* symbol, /t̬/. You can also hear a tap in most of the American English pronunciations there too.

**OK, but why is there no aspiration there?**

The English plosives /p, k, t/ usually occur with some aspiration before vowels (when articulated as plosives, not taps or glottal stops). This may be light or it may be strong depending on it's position in the word. These plosives are usually strongly aspirated when occurring word initially, at the beginning of a stressed syllable or when occurring before a strong vowel. Elsewhere, when occurring before a vowel, /t/ will be lightly aspirated. The exception to this is when the /t/ is preceded by an /s/. When this occurs the /t/ will be completely unaspirated, and will sound like a /d/ to many listeners.

Now this is what actually happens when we get an aspirated consonant in English. The plosives /p, k, t/ are typically voiceless. We make them by forming a complete blockage in the vocal tract which prevents the air from leaving the mouth. Behind this blockage there is a huge build up of air pressure as air is forced up from the lungs. This is called the *hold phase* of the consonant and with voiceless consonants it is accompanied by silence. This is because there is no air moving out of the mouth and the vocal folds (or vocal chords) are not vibrating. When we finally release the air we get an effect called *plosion*, caused by the air exploding out of the mouth.

Now usually these consonants occur before a voiced sound, most often a vowel. Vowels of course are voiced and this is what gives them pitch. So when we make a vowel we vibrate our vocal folds. However our vocal folds are generally a bit lazy when we speak English. They tend to kick in quite late and they often finish early too at the end of a word or syllable. When we get a vowel after a voiceless plosive in English there is a small gap before the vocal folds actually start vibrating. This lag is called the *voice onset time*, or VOT, for short. So the VOT is basically a gap between the release of the plosive and the beginning of the voicing of the vowel.

Now when we release a /p, t/ or /k/ the air that we release is being forced out of the mouth by air coming from the lungs. During the VOT period, before the vocal folds start vibrating, we can hear the turbulence of the air as it leaves the mouth, because there is no vocal fold vibration to drown the noise out. This turbulence that we hear has an /h/-like quality, and it is this sound that we recognise as *aspiration*. So basically aspiration is just the air rushing out of the mouth before the vocal folds get to work.

You will have noticed that I said *when they are articulated as plosives* further above. When /t/ occurs intervocalically (between two vowels) or between /r, l, m, n, ŋ/ and a weak vowel, we see *assimilation*. This means that the /t/ takes on features from the sounds next to it. In particular, it becomes voiced. In practice this means that we don't stop vibrating the vocal folds for the /t/. They vibrate all the way through from the previous sound, right through the /t/ and continue vibrating for the following vowel. It is this aspect of the /t/ that makes it sound like a /d/ to many speakers in words like *water*. The upshot of this is that because there is no gap in the voicing between  the consonant and the following vowel, there is no aspiration.

**Conclusion**

In short the Original Poster is completely correct. It is not that they can't hear the aspiration because  the /t/ is only lightly aspirated in the words *ninety* or  *entertain*. It's that there actually *is* no aspiration in the pronunciations given in the audios from the dictionary. They have used a voiced allophone, instead of [t] for these words. This is not a case of interference from the Original Poster's first language. It's a case of razor sharp ears!

It might be worth mentioning that in British English the use of [ɾ] for /t/ is much rarer. We tend to stick with [t] when American speakers would use [ɾ]. If you listen carefully to the [t]s in the British English versions of the words in the audio, you will be able to hear the light aspiration.

---

Addendum for phonetics junkies

It might be worth mentioning that when we get at /nt/ sequence followed by a weak vowel, in rapid informal speech, the whole /nt/ sequence might get replaced by a single nasalised tap. So for example, we might see [ˈtwɛ̃ɾ̃i] for the word *twenty*. This instance of coalescent assimilation will often be perceived as /t/-elision by listeners.

Comment: Hmm… the first part of this doesn’t seem phonetically accurate. The háček under the t in /t̬/ does not indicate that the consonant is a tap, but that it is _voiced_. Between vowels, this voiced /t̬/ does indeed usually become a tap [ɾ], but that is not the case after a nasal. A tap is defined as “produced with a single contraction of the muscles so that one articulator (such as the tongue) is thrown against another” ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_consonant)), and in the position after a nasal, the tongue is already touching the alveolar ridge and does not move: it’s just a plosive.

Comment: (By “and does not move”, I mean of course that it doesn’t move _before_ the consonant is released—upon release, it does move, naturally. But if it were to be an actual tap, the corona would have to first move away from the ridge and then be brought back into brief contact with it before it was moved away again upon release. The sequence [nɾ] is in fact quite difficult to make, and languages that have [ɾ] often do not have [nɾ], substituting instead something like [nr] or [nd].)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course in terms of striking the ridge you're correct there. What I'm unsure about now is whether there is any anticipatory assimilation on the part of the /n/ such that its not actually a proper nasal stop but something more like a nasalised aproximant. If so, I'm pretty certain it would still be considered a tap, although, of course it isn't a fully articulated flap. My reason for saying this is that if you see [John Well's blog here](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/tap-tap.html) he clearly states that American tapped /t/ can have a lateral release. ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... So my guess is that if they're still considered taps when they have a lateral release, they're probably considered taps when they have a nasal approach. For us to consider them plosives, I suppose we would need some complete stricture to form a blockage. I'm not sure that's happening here. However, I'll ask John Wells on Monday!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Although, I'm going to do a minor edit now, because obviously there is no strike in the case we're most interested in here ... Thanks for pointing all that out! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd be interested in your thoughts on my ad hoc attempt to evade the problem.

Comment: That’s actually very interesting. My gut feeling would be to say that the lateral-release one (and the nasal-release one in _button_) is not a tap—but the closure is clearly not long enough to warrant calling it a true stop, either. It just feels ‘wrong’ somehow to call it a tap when the primary articulator that hits the secondary articulator is a different one from the primary articulator that leaves the secondary articulator. I guess I’d call it a super-brief stop, especially since e.g. some Scottish dialects distinguish /tl/ (/t/, whatever it is, with lateral release) from /rl/ ([ɾl]).

Comment: In the AmE pronunciation of _ninety_ where the /nt/ isn’t reduced to just /n/ or /ɾ̃/, the nasal is definitely a full-on nasal to me, and the word is [ˈnaɪndɨ].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're winning me over. How does *ninety* sound to you [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ninety)? (and can you hear any difference in the /n/?) [May not respond right away. Got to get on a train]

Comment: Oh, I hadn’t actually clicked on the pronunciation tip thingy before. To me, it sounds like she’s saying _nightie_ [ˈnaɪɾi]. I presume she’s probably actually reducing /nt/ to [ɾ̃], making it really [ˈnaɪ̃ɾ̃i], but since that reduction (and the collateral nasalisation of the preceding vowel) is only possible with monophthongs for my AmE, I’m not entirely sure if I can truly hear the difference here, with a dipthong. She definitely sounds _odd_ to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, she sounds a bit odd to me too! I've done an edit to temporarily dodge the tap/plosive conundrum till I can ask JW next week. Does it all seem in order now?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So having conversed with some professional phoneticians, an English tap is just a very short plosive where the hold phase is so short there's not enough time for the air pressure to build up behind the blockage. This is essentially the same thing that's happening here and in *bottle*, which is why they'd both be regarded as  'taps' even though there's no complete ballistic movement.