# Aspiration in American English

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, aspiration

I would like know which consonants are aspirated in American English and when? Also, when are they not aspirated?

Comment: +1 for specifying the variety of English you are enquiring about. The answer would differ in other areas.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Not really: this is not something that varies between dialects.

Comment: The way I speak English, there is a clear difference between 'be top' and 'beat hop'. When I was a child I lived in an area where there was no such distinction for the majority of speakers. I used to fit in with my schoolmates by adopting their accent whilst I was with them and speaking differently when at home. I remember feeling the conflict when I invited friends home.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes. I tend to agree that I would pronounce *be top* differently to *beat hop*.

Comment: @tchrist I hesitate to contradict you on such a matter, but doesn't the Received Pronunciation aspirate both the t in *beat* and the h in *hop* making the sound quite different to *be top*?

Comment: @WS2 - I agree with that analysis and personally I detect a slight glottal stop between the two to further distinguish them.

Comment: I have never in my life had to utter either 'be top' or 'beat hop'. I think that's a dialect difference right there :)

Comment: Relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268218

Answer (score 3):

The unvoiced stops /p, t, k/ at the start of a stressed syllable are “always” aspirated. For example, *be top* and *beat hop* are therefore homophones.

They are occasionally aspirated at the end of an emphatic utterance.

Comment: For me, *be tall* and *beat all* are distinguished by a lack of aspiration in the 't' in *beat all*, while *tall* is aspirated because it's the start of a word.

Comment: This isn't an accurate description of my speech at least. Aspirated t (found in "be top") is distinct from a sequence of coda t and onset h (whether between words like in "beat hop," or within a word as in "adulthood").

Comment: @sumelic "Aspirated t (found in "be top") is distinct from a sequence of coda t and onset h (whether between words like in "beat hop," or within a word as in "adulthood")."                                                                    That's how I hear it, too. I was surprised when I read that "be top" and "beat hop" were homophones.

Answer (score 2):

I'm American, but not an expert on American pronunciation. I would say

- 't' is always aspirated at the start of a stressed syllable: *tall*.
- 't' is never aspirated at the end of an unstressed syllable: *rabbit*.
- 't' is never aspirated after an 's' when they start a syllable: *store, strike*.

I believe that in most other positions, several factors determine the aspiration of the 't' (which words are emphasized, which sound follows a 't' at the end of a syllable, and the speaker's dialect.)

Comment: Can't it be aspirated at the end of a word, even after an unstressed syllable, when pronouncing the word slowly and carefully?

Comment: If you're pronouncing it slowly and carefully because somebody didn't understand the word earlier, sure. But in ordinary speech, I wouldn't expect it to be aspirated. This is why British speakers sound so strange to Americans when they say *at all* ... they aspirate the /t/ in *at all*, which we don't do because *at* is unstressed.